# KOTLIN :How To Call a View within a Function Using ViewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-viewbinding

So with the new Kotlin, Android studio update, it is impossible to call views using their respective ID like the norm, hence viewbinding.
However, I have been trying to call the said view inside a function using the binding method to no success as it keeps returning an error

below is the code:

```
class JobActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val PROGRESS_MAX = 100
private val PROGRESS_START = 0
private val JOB_TIME = 4000 // ms

private lateinit var job: CompletableJob

private lateinit var binding: ActivityJobBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job)


    binding = ActivityJobBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.jobbutton.setOnClickListener {
        if (!::job.isInitialized  ){
            initjob()
        }
    }

}


fun initjob(){
    binding.jobbutton.setText("StartJob #1")
    binding.textView2.setText("")
    job= Job()
    job.invokeOnCompletion {
        it?.message.let {
            var msg = it
            if (msg.isNullOrBlank()){
                msg ="Uknown cancellation Error"
            }
            println("${job} was cancelled. Reason:$msg")
            showtoast(msg)
        }
    }
    binding.progressBar.max= PROGRESS_MAX
    binding.progressBar.progress= PROGRESS_START

}
fun showtoast(text:String){
    Toast.makeText(this@JobActivity, text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
  }
fun ProgressBar.startJobOrCancel(job: Job) {
if (this.progress > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "${job} is already active. Cancelling...")
    resetjob()
} else {
    binding.jobbutton.setText("StartJob #1")
    Log.d(TAG, "coroutine ${this} is activated with job ${job}.")

}
}
```

the error occurs here:

[image]

please provide precise steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First thing's first, remove the OnCreate method its redundant and unnecessary:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_job)
```

2.You can decide to go back to the initial Kotlin method of calling views in the activity by their respective ID by adding this line (ps: this is the updated way of adding plugins in the new kotlin version 1.4.0:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

using this method, it is possible to do it the original way but slight warning,, you may be susceptible to calling null operations.

Answer (score 3):

@GabrielFranciss

mmm, i think the binding object its not recognized outside the extension function, you must add the binding as a parameter, or, create a lambda function that could be invoked when the extension function executes and concludes.

```kotlin
fun ProgressBar.startJobOrCancel(job:Job, jobStarted: () -> Unit ) {
  when {
    this.progress > 0 -> {
      //log
      resetJob()
    }
    else -> {
      jobFinished()
    }
  }
}
```

And using the function in the activity/fragment as follows:

```kotlin
  private var job = Job()
  private var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default+job)
  /* inside initJob() ... */
  job = scope.launch(){
    binding.progress.startJobOrCancel(job) {
      binding.jobbutton.setText("StartJob #1")
    }
  }
```

#### Update (2020-11-17):

On the `onCreate` function inside the activity, remove the duplicated call to `setContentView`:

```kotlin
  ...
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_job) /* remove this if you're using view binding */
  binding = ActivityJobBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
  setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: @Marlom Lopez  one question, how will we call it with the binding though, I have honestly tried your approach but its not working.

Comment: @marlon lopez, kindly show how you add the binding as a parameter

Comment: @SaginiChan the binding is not added as the parameter, i mean, in the snippet, i used a lambda function as a parameter (aka, a hig order function), with that, the function is called inside the function that executes the Job.

In the UI screen,  the usage of the high order function could be similar to the usage of the anonymous interface in the java methods. (cont...)

Comment: @SaginiChan (cont...) you can check the kotlin documentation for the usage of the lambdas as a function parameter (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) ...

Comment: @GabrielFranciss ... the binding object is used in the implementation of the high order function, which is passed as a parameter in the extension function.

I used the same code that you shared for the usage of the function. so, its easy to understand. keep in mind something, the job is executed as a coroutine, so, you could check that the function thats executed ater the extension function is called in the ui scope

Answer (score 1):

You should remove this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_job)
```

and in case of not using ViewBinding, you can use Kotlin Android Extensions by adding this plugin in Gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and just call view by its id!
for example for TextView with this line of code:

```
 android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
```

you can easily call :

```
welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
```

Comment: mmm, i think using synthetic imports is not a recommended way to solve this. pls check this link for detail -> https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/